# How to create rss feeds (.xml) for our own dynamic site while using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, rss, sitemap

I've tried every method that I knows but didn't got the solution on "How to create an rss feeds and sitemap for a dynamic site that get updated automatically".

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea is to have your php file generate a valid RSS (xml) based on your database results. So, select the data you want to show from the MySQL db, and output them, conforming to the [rss standard](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/w-rss.html).

Check [the top three google results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=&q=php+rss+generator&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_en___BG265&ie=UTF-8&aq=4&oq=php+rss)

For the sitemap it will be a little harder, and it greatly depends on your structure, which is unknown to us. But the principle is the same - output a valid xml file conforming to the [sitemap standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map), based on the pages you want to show.